# VSFTP Not Working After Static IP Change

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd, static-ip, winscp

Basically this is the deal. I install vsftpd everything was working fine with dynamic ip and these vsftpd.config settings, could easily access through winscp:

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=Yes
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
local_umask=022
local_root=/
#
#
#SSL
rsa_cert_file=/home/me/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/home/me/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
```

Than i changed the server from dynamic to static ip & i got everything to work normally, SSH, websites, email, etc. EXCEPT for FTP. My FTP is completely broken using vsftpd settings, Cannot connect via WINSCP or FileZilla and I do not know what to do anymore, I played around with it for hours. Any this is what I got my setting at so far to make sure vsftpd actually runs giving at OK. But even after it running, I still cannot connect via WINSCP.

```
Restarting vsftpd (via systemctl): vsftpd.service.
root@mail:/etc# /etc/init.d/vsftpd status -l
â vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; vendor     preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-12-14 07:11:04 EST; 3s ago
  Process: 19821 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/vsftpd/empty     (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 19824 (vsftpd)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 392.0K
      CPU: 4ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/vsftpd.service
           ââ19824 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Current Settings: /etc/vsftpd.conf

```
#listen=NO
#listen_ipv6=Yes
listen=Yes
#listen_address=domain.com
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
local_umask=022
#
#pasv_enable=Yes
#port_enable=YES
#pasv_min_port=2
#pasv_max_port=98000
#connect_from_port_20=Yes
#connect_from_port_21=yes
#pasv_address=domain.com
#pasv_addr_resolve=YES
#
#SSL
rsa_cert_file=/home/me/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/home/me/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
```

Comment: Did you restart the service after change of IP? Do you have firewall run?

Comment: Firewall is off. Running UFW: status inactive. Yes I restarted the service a million times.

Comment: Do you use SSL/TLS to access server? Because you have wrong configuration of SSL section.

Comment: TLS/SSL Explict. But i had these settings on before when the IP of server was dynamic and it was fine. connection went through.

Comment: Have you try to use openssl command to access the server (to see the result)? Something like: `openssl s_client <ip>:<port>`